# Inline function definition

Tags: c#, lambda

For better readability, I want to define inline functions in C#, like this one:

```
var HasFullAccess = (mask => mask % 2 == 1);
foreach(AccessControlEntry ace in acl)
{
    if(HasFullAccess(ace.AccessMask)) ...
```

The problem is the `var`. I guess I have to put sth. there that tells C# to expect a lambda expression? I also tried

```
(int => bool) HasFullAccess = (mask => mask % 2 == 1);
```

which also does not work. So how can I define an inline function?

Comment: `Func<int,bool> HasFullAccess  = ...`

Comment: I'd rather use `(mask & 1) != 0` which is the idiomatic way to check flags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this

```
Func<int,bool> HasFullAccess = mask => mask % 2 == 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

like this

```
var hasFullAccess = new Func<int, bool>(mask => mask % 2 == 1);
```

or this,

```
Func<int, bool> hasFullAccess = mask => mask % 2 == 1;
```

for other types of function you'll need to use a compatible delegate type. You have to give the compiler some help.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assign a lambda expression to an implicitly-typed local variable (as the compiler should have pointed out). You will have to specify your delegate type (in this case `Func<int, bool>`) explicitly.

```
var HasFullAccess = new Func<int, bool>(mask => mask % 2 == 1);
```

Or, alternatively

```
Func<int, bool> HasFullAccess = mask => mask % 2 == 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Standard way to do this is to define this helper function:

```
public static Func<A, T> func<A, T>(Func<A, T> f)
{
    return f;
}
```

somewhere in your namespace. Then you can call

```
var myfunc = func((int mask) => mask % 2 == 1);
```

and it will happily infer the type for you.